# integrate as class library in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, svg, simplexml, scale

I need to integrate the code that is in the answer to this thread.

[How to rotate SVG by PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17948763/how-to-rotate-svg-by-php)

When I do it as a library I get error "construct", I do not have much knowledge about it, I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

From this class:

```
class ExSimpleXMLElement extends SimpleXMLElement 
{ 


    public function _construct($xml){
        parent::_construct($xml);
    }

    /** 
     * Add SimpleXMLElement code into a SimpleXMLElement 
     * @param SimpleXMLElement $append 
     */ 
    public function appendXML($append) 
    { 
        if ($append) { 
            if (strlen(trim((string) $append))==0) { 
                $xml = $this->addChild($append->getName()); 
                foreach($append->children() as $child) { 
                    $xml->appendXML($child); 
                } 
            } else { 
                $xml = $this->addChild($append->getName(), (string) $append); 
            }     
            foreach($append->attributes() as $n => $v) { 
                $xml->addAttribute($n, $v); 
            } 
         } 
     } 
}
```

You would transform it like this:

```
<?php

class ExSimpleXMLElement
{ 
    private $sxe;

    public function loadXml($xml){
        $this->sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
    }

    /** 
    * Add SimpleXMLElement code into a SimpleXMLElement 
    * @param SimpleXMLElement $append 
    */ 
    public function appendXML($append) 
    {
        if ($append) { 
            if (strlen(trim((string) $append))==0) { 
                $xml = $this->sxe->addChild($append->getName()); 
                foreach($append->children() as $child) { 
                    $xml->appendXML($child); 
                } 
            } else { 
                $xml = $this->sxe->addChild($append->getName(), (string) $append); 
            }     
            foreach($append->attributes() as $n => $v) { 
                $xml->addAttribute($n, $v); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

And use it like this:

```
$this->load->library('ExSimpleXMLElement');

$this->exsimplexmlelement->loadXML($xml);
```

Comment: machineaddict. I tried the code and I get the error image, which can be? I'm calling the liberia so:

[link] (https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4eow_YS2Y1eVjFaQV9HRlNCcWM/edit)

``public function edit_svg(){

        $this->load->library('ExSimpleXMLElement');
        $file="images/designs/svg/a.svg";


//http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?165648-Editing-XML-using-PHP
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file); //Load the File. 

$this->exsimplexmlelement->loadXML($xml)``

Comment: Instead of `$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);`, use `$xml = file_get_contents($file);`. The `loadXML` method needs xml as string.

Comment: thanks!, what you said worked, but now I have another error! the controller related to liberia, calling the method "appendXML ()" 

Might you help me with this ... I have tried to correct it during the day but I have not done it! 


``Fatal error: Call to undefined method SimpleXMLElement::appendXML() in C:\wamp\www\m3\trunk\application\controllers\svg.php``

controller: 
[svg](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4eow_YS2Y1eUkNtT1B6YlFsV28/edit)

library:
[ExSimpleXMLElement](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4eow_YS2Y1eUnUtc1VwaWNRMUE/edit)